# How to set a tag to UICollectionView - SWIFT - Multiple CollectionViews on same screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, tags, uicollectionview

I have multiple UICollectionView on same screen. I know that with Objective-C I can set a tag of each CollectionView like the code below. But I can't figure out how to do the same on Swift

```
[self.collectionViewOne   setTag:1];
[self.collectionViewTwo   setTag:2];
[self.collectionViewThree setTag:3];

//Then say inside "cellForItemAtIndexPath" if tag is equal then...
if(collectionView.tag==1)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.collectionViewOne.tag = 1

if(collectionView.tag == 1)
{
  //...
}
```

Is that what you mean? It's exactly the same thing.

That said, why not just compare the actual objects instead of using tags?

```
if(collectionView == self.collectionViewOne)
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: I've already tried --> self.collectionView?.tag = 1 <-- but was making the app crash. The problem was that I had the collectionView declared two times../ Anyway both of your solutions works and I like the second. Thanks!! @Dima